# Automatically calculate age after focus change

Tags: java, netbeans

Can you please help me on how to Automatically calculate age after selecting date from datepicker and when focus is changed from datepicker to age textfiel the age calculates?

[Sample Form Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMlcc.jpg)

Comment: Which date picker are you using?

Comment: Maybe a `FocusListener` would help, see [How to Write a Focus Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html).  I'd also use JodaTime or Java 8's Time API to calculate the Age...

Comment: @MadProgrammer jxdatepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `FocusListener` will help, for example...

```
    JXDatePicker dp = new JXDatePicker();
    dp.getEditor().addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            // Calculate age
            Date date = dp.getDate();
        }
    });
```

See [How to Write a Focus Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html) for more details

The age calculation is best done using either JodaTime or Java 8's new Time API

## Java 8

```
Date date = // Date from date picker
LocalDate ld = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

//LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(1972, Month.MARCH, 8);
Period p = Period.between(ld, LocalDate.now());
System.out.println(p.getYears());
System.out.println(p.getMonths());
System.out.println(p.getDays());
```

Which outputs something like...

```
42
11
18
```

## Joda-Time

```
Date date = // Date from date picker
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.fromDateFields(date);

Period p = Period.fieldDifference(ld, LocalDate.now());
System.out.println(p.getYears());
System.out.println(p.getMonths());
System.out.println(p.getDays());
```