# I have made an age calculator but It is showing negative values

Tags: java

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.Console;

public class AgeCalculator
{
    static Console c;

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        c = new Console ();
        //Variable Declaration
        int days;
        int month;
        int year;

        days = 0;
        month = 0;
        year = 0;

        //I used Ready To Program IDE
        c.println ("This program calculates your age to the exact date");

        c.println ();

        c.println ("Please answer in numerical format day/month/year (Eg: 1/1/2016)");

        c.println ();


        //Input Section
        c.print ("Please enter the day you were born in: ");
        days = c.readInt ();
        c.println ();

        c.print ("Please enter the month you were born in: ");
        month = c.readInt ();
        c.println ();

        c.print ("Please enter the year you were born in: ");
        year = c.readInt ();
        c.clear();

        //Processing Section
        // This is where the calculations are happening and I believe this is where I am making a mistake
        c.println ("Date of Birth: " + days + "/" + month + "/" + year);
        Date d = new Date ();
        c.println ("Current Date: " + d.getDate () + "/" + (d.getMonth () + 1) + "/" + (d.getYear () + 1900));

        days = d.getDate () + 30 - days;
        month = d.getMonth () + 1 - month;
        year = d.getYear () + 1900 - year;

        //Output Section
        c.println ("Age:" + year + " years " + month + " months " + days + " days "); //Displays age in years,month, and days


    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, it will show negative values. For example, if the current month is Feb, and I enter a date in January - it will show a negative number of months.

Comment: Date calculations are very involved and require a series of if but elses, to put it bluntly, you're better off making use of the available APIs, like Java 8's Date/Time API, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734277/automatically-calculate-age-after-focus-change/28734421#28734421)

Comment: your algorithm is incorrect. try doing some math how to calculate time interval between two dates

Answer (score 0):

Before printing final output add following lines of code to get the correct result :

```
days = d.getDate () - days;
    month = d.getMonth () + 1 - month;
    year = d.getYear () + 1900 - year;

if(days<0){
    days = days + 30;
    month = month - 1;
}
if(month<0)
{
    month = month + 12;
    year = year - 1;
}
```